# UpdateSubscription generates (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am trying to update an existing Subscription in Azure Service Bus but getting (500) Internal Server Error. My code is as below:

```
        NamespaceManager nmg = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://My service bus endpoint with SAS");

        SubscriptionDescription sd = nmg.GetSubscription("topicname", "subscriptionName");

        sd.ForwardTo = "TopicNameToForward";

        nmg.UpdateSubscription(sd);
```

I get the error on UpdateSubscription. There are no more details in the error. Also I am able to do all other operations (like create Topic, create subscriptions, etc) but error only happens if I try to set the "ForwardTo" value. Please Help

Comment: Also, any customizations to the two topics?

Comment: No, no customization made to any topic other than trying to set the Forward To field.

Comment: All entities are in the same namespace and exist (silly question, but trying to rule things out).

Comment: Yes, all entities are in same namespace.

Comment: At this point I'd say try another namespace. John's answer is correct, either the entity forwarded to doesn't exist, or something is fishy.

Comment: Just retried my code and it started working. So I think something was wrong on Azure side because it wasn't working for 3 days (i.e. 5/25 to 5/27)

Comment: Things can happen. Make sure you use the latest ASB and have a reference number from the exception to supply to support. That way there will be less guessing 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 500 internal server error will be returned if the ForwardTo property is not set to a valid Topic that exists when UpdateSubscription() is called.

For example this will fail if "mytopic2" does not exist.

```
        var nsManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);

        if (!await nsManager.TopicExistsAsync(TopicName))
        {
            await nsManager.CreateTopicAsync(TopicName);
        }

        if (!await nsManager.SubscriptionExistsAsync(TopicName, SubscriptionName))
        {
            await nsManager.CreateSubscriptionAsync(TopicName, SubscriptionName);
        }

        var subDesc = await nsManager.GetSubscriptionAsync(TopicName, SubscriptionName);

        subDesc.ForwardTo = "myTopic2";

        await nsManager.UpdateSubscriptionAsync(subDesc);
```

Comment: My code started working, so I think there was some issue on Azure side.